# to write csv file in python after 24 hours automatically?

Tags: python, csv, datetime

- get current time and date
- to write csv file

What is the module and method used to write CSV file in python after 24 hours automatically?

Comment: The method is called "software engineering". Which means you have to do a bit of research on your own first. Dividing your problems into sub-problems - as you've done already - is a good approach. Now you can search for solutions of those sub-problems in order to create your final solution (attempt). I'm sure you'll find lots of inputs for those on SO.

Comment: if the op system is unix based, I suggest using the cronjob to trigger simple python script that writes to csv file

Comment: i'm windows user shahaf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For writing a CSV file I would use [python's CSV module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html).
Here's a simple example from CSV module documentation for writing a CSV file:

```
import csv

with open('eggs.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

For scheduling things [schedule library](https://github.com/dbader/schedule) seems to be pretty good.
Here's a simple scheduling example from that github page:

```
import schedule
import time

def job():
    print("I'm working...")

schedule.every(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().hour.do(job)
schedule.every().day.at("10:30").do(job)
schedule.every(5).to(10).minutes.do(job)
schedule.every().monday.do(job)
schedule.every().wednesday.at("13:15").do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: how to stop the will loop

Comment: You'll need to design some logic to stop it, maybe some key combination etc. Or you could just kill the process when it's not needed anymore.